# Editing custom fields in Devise User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, web, devise, strong-parameters

The fields were added via migration and the view's forms are created, but the controller filters the parameter on their path from the view to the model. No matter what I seem to do, my parameters are always unpermitted.  My controller code

#app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)<<[:first_name,:last_name,:profile_image,:graduation_year]
  end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_account_update_params
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update)<<[:first_name,:last_name,:profile_image,:graduation_year]
  end

end
end
```

#config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
#...

  devise_for :users, controllers: { account_update: "users/registrations", sign_up:"users/registrations" }
end
```

#Error

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Qts15L3n6Xvsn0hwNvIUI6UrWUQyV/qEyoQAZ8M+udMK1RBTQS1XoNWgpg1JrXqWpb9NbrsaHtQVVU8XMwoSIQ==", 
 "user"=>{"first_name"=>"a", "last_name"=>"a", 
 "profile_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000004fe0bb0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150709-4420-12guerh.jpeg>, @original_filename="test1.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[profile_image]\"; filename=\"test1.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, 
 "graduation_year"=>"1", "email"=>"aaaaaa@a.a", 
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, 
 "commit"=>"Submit"}

Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name, profile_image, graduation_year
```

Thanks for the help everyone. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry mate but the error ended up being in the routes file, I shared my answer below. The original syntax for the configure_params methods works fine, though yours is much cleaner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My config/routes.rb was messed up. It needed to be

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations'  }
```

Then I needed to add :email, :password, :password_confirmation back to app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)<<[:first_name,:last_name,:profile_image,:graduation_year,
       :email,:password,:password_confirmation]
  end

  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update)<<[:first_name,:last_name,:profile_image,:graduation_year,
       :email,:password,:password_confirmation]
  end
end
```

Also there was an extra 'end' at the bottom of the file.

**Update**

In the current version of devise (4.3)/rails (5.1.3) it is similar, but the configure functions should be updated to something like this:

```
def configure_sign_up_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :age, :height, :weight, :gender])
end
```

Comment: To use configure_sign_up_params you also need to uncomment a line at the top of the controller so it gets called.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and changing like the below worked for me.

```
def configure_sign_up_params
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit( :first_name, :last_name, :profile_image, :graduation_year) }
end

def configure_account_update_params
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit( :first_name, :last_name, :profile_image, :graduation_year) }
end
```

Comment: Thanks mate I'll check this when I can and report back